# Does some food increase pollen allergy symptoms?

Tags: allergy, food-safety, pollen

As a pollen allergic, should I avoid of eating some kinds of food which may increase pollen allergy symptoms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are foods that won't increase your pollen allergy symptoms, but instead cause them. This is a condition called Oral Allergy Syndrome, also known as Pollen-Food Allergy Syndrome.<sup>[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oral_allergy_syndrome)</sup> This is caused by a reaction to foods that contain similar ingredients or proteins to the type of pollen they are allergic to. So while this allergy is a bit different than just a regular pollen allergy, it is likely that, if you have a pollen allergy, there will be foods that trigger the same symptoms you may get from your pollen allergies.<sup>[2](https://www.rush.edu/health-wellness/discover-health/pollen-food-allergy-syndrome)</sup>

There are a few common types of pollen allergies that have foods associated with them. Ragweed allergy, which is caused by the pollen of ragweed and mainly causes symptoms like sneezing, itchy throat, stuffy/runny nose, and possible trouble breathing. Some of the foods that may cause these symptoms include watermelons, cantaloupes, bananas, and honey.<sup>[3](http://acaai.org/allergies/types/ragweed-allergy)</sup>

A birch pollen allergy is also a common allergy which has many symptoms similar to those of ragweed allergy. Foods which many trigger those symptoms are kiwi, pears, apples, plums, cherries, carrots, and almonds. Grass pollen allergy is the other common type of pollen allergy and its symptoms, which are also like ragweed and birch allergy symptoms, can be triggered by foods like tomatoes, celery, peaches, and oranges. To help avoid the above mentioned foods, you can try many things, such as cooking the food or peeling it, if it is possible.<sup>[4](http://www.webmd.com/allergies/features/oral-allergy-syndrome-foods)</sup>

---

<sup>[1: Oral Allergy Syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oral_allergy_syndrome)</sup>

<sup>[2: Recognizing pollen food allergy syndrome](https://www.rush.edu/health-wellness/discover-health/pollen-food-allergy-syndrome)</sup>

<sup>[3: Rag Weed Allergy](http://acaai.org/allergies/types/ragweed-allergy)</sup>

<sup>[4: Foods That May Worsen Pollen Allergies](http://www.webmd.com/allergies/features/oral-allergy-syndrome-foods)</sup>